# Repartition luks encrypted disk to add a partition

Tags: partitioning, debian, vmware, luks

I have installed Debian on VMware, I think I chose one of the `debian-installer` options to manage luks encryption and LVM partitions with separate `/home`, `/var` and `/tmp` partitions.

Here is the output of `lsblk --fs`

```
NAME                   FSTYPE      FSVER            LABEL                 UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                                                             
├─sda1                 ext2        1.0                                    21f51333-4c72-4877-af5e-2602878d3ffc    356.5M    19% /boot
├─sda2                                                                                                                          
└─sda5                 crypto_LUKS 2                                      43b6f75d-1fa7-4f01-af1a-e88707ec46cc                  
  └─sda5_crypt         LVM2_member LVM2 001                               gxNHfE-42eG-UKpG-fW7X-2uQ4-rfbk-Aj6pN3                
    ├─serve--vg-root   ext4        1.0                                    00489a43-5fea-4543-a8fb-45d2dcd3e36e      2.5G    31% /
    ├─serve--vg-var    ext4        1.0                                    d684e9ec-4883-4eee-8bff-75fc567c6521      1.2G    18% /var
    ├─serve--vg-swap_1 swap        1                                      2c9c2019-774a-4871-8b6e-ea2545e8b5e0                  [SWAP]
    ├─serve--vg-tmp    ext4        1.0                                    04f48838-b066-4a37-b905-a4aa42247d8e    320.3M     0% /tmp
    └─serve--vg-home   ext4        1.0                                    66a1138f-6a0b-461b-862c-ad57ea3d6583     11.6G     0% /home
```

I am looking for a good method to add partitions to the `luks` volume without breaking stuff (I am planning to add new hard disks using `VMware` to use for audit logs). The new partitions needs to be included in the luks lvm.

```
Vmware Fusion - Professional Version 13.0.2
  Host : MacOS Ventura 13.4.1
  Debian : Bullseye 11.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there are, broadly, two approaches to take:

1. Increase the size of the existing disk in VMware. After increasing the size of the disk, the `sda5` partition on the disk would need to be resized to account for the new size of the disk (**this would involve recreating the partition table**). Then, the Physical Volume `sda5_crypt` could be resized to take up the remaining size of the now-larger partition. Then, the relevant Logical Volumes could be extended to make use of the extra space. Finally, the filesystem on the logical volume that was extended would need to be grown.
2. Add additional disks from VMware. After adding the disks, they will need to be encrypted with LUKS. Then, the additional disk can be added to a new Physical Volume in LVM. Then, the new physical volume can be added to the Volume Group. Then, the relevant Logical Volumes could be extended to make use of the extra space. Finally, the filesystem on the logical volume that was extended would need to be grown.

Option 1 requires fiddling with the partition table, but shouldn't require any adjustments to the boot sequence once it is complete. The operating system, presumably, already knows to decrypt the LUKS partition and then let LVM manage the decrypted storage. Option 2 avoids fiddling with the partition table of any disks, but may require adjusting the boot sequence to decrypt the additional disk on boot as well so that it is available to LVM. In theory, you may only need to add an entry to `/etc/crypttab` for the new disk, but I have not tested that. Helpful context: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390159/38029

And some documentation on systemd's behaviour wrt /etc/crypttab:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptsetup@.service.html#

> At early boot and when the system manager configuration is reloaded, /etc/crypttab is translated into systemd-cryptsetup@.service units by systemd-cryptsetup-generator(8).

Comment: I will probably go with the 2nd option, I will accept your answer and edit my question with the detailed steps when I will finish